# Storing values from AJAX requests in Flask?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

So far, I have the following function that checks NLP values of the messages that user sends to the chatbot. I would want to store these values so that if user sends 10 messages, `textToneSum` is the sum of all  `textTone` values. I will use this data later in another function with help of Session. However, as the chat function is called with AJAX every time user clicks a button to send a message, `textToneSum` never gathers values from more than one message. How would I solve this? There is probably an easy solution but my brain feels stuck.

```
@app.route('/chat', methods=['GET','POST'])
def chat():
    textToneSum = 0
    message = request.args.get('message')
    textSample = TextBlob (message) 
    textTone = textSample.sentiment.polarity 
    textSubj = textSample.sentiment.subjectivity
    textToneSum+=textTone
    print("sum is", textToneSum)
    #some irrelevant code deleted here
    session['textToneSum'] = textToneSum
    return jsonify(result = response_text, texttone = textTone, textsubj = textSubj)
```

Comment: You can save value to user cookie, which persists between requests.

Comment: That was the solution, thanks!